# How to create a string-parameterized wrapper around an arbitrary function in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I would like to generate wrappers in such way that for an arbitrary function

```
R func(A a, B b, ...)
```

an

```
std::function<std::string (std::vector<std::string>)>
```

is returned which wraps `f` so that the parameters are taken from the vector and are (attempted to be) converted with `boost::lexical_cast`, same for the return value. 
For example:

```
int add(int a, int b);

auto f = magic_wrap(&add);
auto result = f(std::vector<std::string>{"2", "3"});
// result == "5"
```

My intuition tells me this should be possible with variadic templates, but I'm stuck on getting the return and parameter types for the function. Is this possible somehow and if so, how?

Comment: You can't unpack a `std::vector` (which has unknown compile-time length) into a parameter list.

Comment: A function parameter list is not a list ;-) You could certainly simplify your work if all of your functions took a single list as a parameter list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not knowledgable about `boost::lexical_cast` but I think this should work:

```
template<std::size_t... Is>
struct index_sequence
{ };

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct make_index_sequence : make_index_sequence<N - 1, N - 1, Is...>
{ };

template<std::size_t... Is>
struct make_index_sequence<0, Is...> : index_sequence<Is...>
{ };

template<typename R, typename... Args>
class wrapped
{
public:
    explicit
    wrapped(R (&func)(Args...))
        : func_(func)
    {
    }

public:
    std::string operator()(std::vector<std::string> args)
    {
        if (sizeof...(Args) != args.size()) {
            throw std::logic_error("Incorrect number of arguments");
        }

        auto const& result = invoke(make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>(),
                                    args);
        return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(result);
    }

private:
    template<std::size_t... Is>
    R invoke(index_sequence<Is...>, std::vector<std::string> const& args)
    {
        return func_(boost::lexical_cast<Args>(args[Is])...);
    }

private:
    R (*func_)(Args...);
};

template<typename R, typename... Args>
std::function<std::string (std::vector<std::string>)>
wrap(R (&func)(Args...))
{
    return wrapped<R, Args...>(func);
}
```

You can see a working demo of a slightly modified version (one that doesn't use Boost) [here](http://ideone.com/L5fuki).